# Вызвать метод объекта из коллекции

Tags: java, list, коллекции

Имеются интерфейсы:

```
public interface Ancor {

void toShoot();//Дальний бой
void toDamage();//Ближний бой

}

public interface Mag {

void toBless();//Благословить отряд союзника
void magicDamage();//Атака магией
void toCurse();//Снять благословение у противника
```

}

```
public interface Warrior {

void toDamage();//Ближний бой
```

}

их реализуют следующие классы:

```
public class ElfAncor implements Ancor {

private Integer damage;
private  Integer hp = 100;

public ElfAncor() {
    System.out.println("Эльф - лучник создан!");

}

public Integer getDamage() {
    return damage;
}

public void setDamage(Integer damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
}

public Integer getHp() {
    return hp;
}

public void setHp(Integer hp) {
    this.hp = hp;
}

public void toShoot() {
    setDamage(7);
}

public void toDamage() {
    setDamage(3);
}
}


public class ElfWarrior implements Warrior {

private Integer damage;
private  Integer hp = 100;

public ElfWarrior() {
    System.out.println("Эльф - воин создан!");

}

public Integer getDamage() {
    return damage;
}

public void setDamage(Integer damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
}

public Integer getHp() {
    return hp;
}

public void setHp(Integer hp) {
    this.hp = hp;
}

public void toDamage() {
    setDamage(15);
}
}

public class ElfMag implements Mag {

private Integer damage;
private  Integer hp = 100;

public ElfMag() {
    System.out.println("Эльф - маг создан!");
}

public Integer getDamage() {
    return damage;
}

public void setDamage(Integer damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
}

public Integer getHp() {
    return hp;
}

public void setHp(Integer hp) {
    this.hp = hp;
}

public void toBless() {

}

public void magicDamage() {
    setDamage(10);
}

public void toCurse() {

}
}
```

Мне нужно из коллекции, содержащей данные объекты, получить доступ к методам объекта

```
 public static List firstTeam = new LinkedList();

 public ElfAncor elfAncor1, elfAncor2, elfAncor3;
public ElfMag elfMag1;
public ElfWarrior elfWarrior1, elfWarrior2, elfWarrior3, elfWarrior4;


firstTeam.add(elfAncor1 = new ElfAncor());
        firstTeam.add(elfAncor2 = new ElfAncor());
        firstTeam.add(elfAncor3 = new ElfAncor());
        firstTeam.add(elfMag1 = new ElfMag());
        firstTeam.add(elfWarrior1 = new ElfWarrior());
        firstTeam.add(elfWarrior2 = new ElfWarrior());
        firstTeam.add(elfWarrior3 = new ElfWarrior());
        firstTeam.add(elfWarrior4 = new ElfWarrior());
```

Как получить доступ к методам объекта?

Comment: а вы ранее не задавали похожий вопрос? только в нем Archer было написано без ошибок.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, не

```
public static List firstTeam = new LinkedList();
```

а

```
public static List<ElfAncor> firstTeam = new LinkedList<>();
```

возможно даже

```
public static List<Ancor> firstTeam = new LinkedList<>();
```

Иначе в коллекцию можно совать любые объекты, а не только с нужным типом.

Во-вторых, совершенно не ясна надпись

```
firstTeam.add(elfAncor1 = new ElfAncor());
firstTeam.add(elfAncor2 = new ElfAncor());
firstTeam.add(elfAncor3 = new ElfAncor());
```

Каким образом ты пытаешься одновременно создать объект, воткнуть в список и еще присвоить неизведанной переменной. Если ты записываешь в коллекцию, то и работай с ней.

```
firstTeam.add(new ElfAncor());
firstTeam.add(new ElfAncor());
firstTeam.add(new ElfAncor());
```

Например вот вывод `hp` всех эльфов:

```
for (ElfAncor elfAncor : firstTeam) {
    System.out.println(elfAncor.getHp());
}
```

Если так сильно хочется обратиться к конкретному объекту, то обращайся по индексу коллекции к примеру:

```
System.out.println(firstTeam.get(1).getHp());
```

Comment: немного поясню. В коллекцию я хочу добавить не три объекта одного класса, а другое количество из разных классов. Код сверху обновил

Comment: Таким образом, получается что коллекция хранит разные объекты. При проходе коллекции, мне нужно получить объект, и использовать его методы. КАК?

Comment: @Mishustiq какие именно методы? Если toShoot и toDamage - то я написал в ответе, если другие то если коллекция вида `List<Ancor>` надо кастовать к нужному классу например `((ElfAncor)elfAncor).getHp()` .... хотя и `getHp` можно вынести в интерфейс.... а проще наверное в абстрактный класс

Comment: Обновил вопрос)

Comment: @Mishustiq Ну не, я так не играю. Это так можно до завтрашнего утра постоянно обновлять вопрос и добалять всё новые данные, которые поворачивают всё в другое русло. Можно ведь сразу написать как следует. и до сих пор не ясно, **какие именно** методы ты не можешь вызвать и в какой момент

Comment: Извини))Это что касается эльфив - все

Comment: тут еще интереснее. Я хочу вызывать все методы, которые я переопределял из интерфейса

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял ты хочешь хранить в одной команде разных типов персонажей и вызывать их методы. Для этого можно наследовать все интерфейсы от одного и создавать лист этого интерфейса, когда необходимо расширять до необходимого наследного класса.

```
public interface ParentInterface {
    void gethp();
}
interface ChaildInterface1 extends ParentInterface {
}
interface ChaildInterface2 extends ParentInterface {
}
interface ChaildInterface3 extends ParentInterface {
}
class Warrior implements ChaildInterface1 {

@Override
public Integer getHP() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void getDemage() {

}
}


LinkedList<ParentInterface> list = new LinkedList();
    list.add(new Warrior());
    list.add(new Warrior());
    for (ParentInterface anPers : list) {
        System.out.println(anPers.getHP());
        if (anPers instanceof Warrior){
            ((Warrior) anPers).getDemage();
        }
    }
```